# How to add archiving version information to a structure in boost

Tags: boost, archive

```
When i try adding version information to a structure i get error "boost::serialization::version': 'SumPoint' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T' "
```

How can i add version number to the archive of this structure.

```
BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(SumPoint, 1)
struct SumPoint
{
    SumPoint() = default;
    explicit SumPoint(float val) : x{ val }, y{ val }, z{ val } {}
    SumPoint(float X, float Y, float Z) : x{ X }, y{ Y }, z{ Z } {}
    SumPoint(float X, float Y, float Z, bool _isSmooth) : x{ X }, y{ Y }, z{ Z }, isSmooth{ _isSmooth }{}
    float x{ 0.0f };
    float y{ 1.0f };
    float z{ 1.0f };
    bool isSmooth{ false };
    

    SumPoint& operator = (const SumPoint& point) { x = point.x; y = point.y; z = point.z; isSmooth = point.isSmooth; return *this; }
    SumPoint operator + (const SumPoint& point) { SumPoint poi; poi.x = x + point.x; poi.y = y + point.y;  poi.z = z + point.z;  return poi; }
    SumPoint operator - (const SumPoint& point) { SumPoint poi; poi.x = x - point.x; poi.y = y - point.y;  poi.z = z - point.z;  return poi; }
    bool operator == (const SumPoint& point) { return x == point.x && y == point.y && z == point.z && isSmooth == point.isSmooth; }
    bool operator != (const SumPoint& point) { return x != point.x || y != point.y || z != point.z || isSmooth == point.isSmooth;}

    void SetPoint(float X, float Y, float Z) { x = X ; y = Y ; z = Z; } 
    

    SumPoint& rotL90(unsigned char axis) {
        float f;
        switch (toupper(axis)) {
        case 'X': f = z; z = -y; y = f; break;
        case 'Y': f = z; z = -x; x = f; break;
        case 'Z': f = y; y = -x; x = f; break;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    void normalize() {
        float length = sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z));
        x = x / length;
        y = y / length;
        z = z / length;
    }

    float Distance(SumPoint p) {
        return std::sqrt(powf( p.x - x , 2) + pow( p.y - y , 2) + pow(p.z - z , 2));
    }   

    glm::vec2 ToGlmVector() { return glm::vec2(x, y); }


    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) const {
        ar & x & y & z;
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {

        
        ar& x& y& z;
        
    }
    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is *very simple*. You try to set the version for the type *before declaring it*. In fact, a simple forward declaration will do:

```
struct SumPoint;
BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(SumPoint, 1)
```

Of course, you could also move it to after the declaration.

Here's a version with many simplifications

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8d48a613b046d67)**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <glm/vec2.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct SumPoint;
BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(SumPoint, 1)

struct SumPoint {
    SumPoint() = default;
    SumPoint(float X, float Y, float Z, bool smooth = false) : x{X}, y{Y}, z{Z}, isSmooth{smooth} {}
    explicit SumPoint(float X) : SumPoint(X, X, X) {}

    float x        = 0;
    float y        = 1;
    float z        = 1;
    bool  isSmooth = false;

    SumPoint operator-(SumPoint const& p) const { return {x - p.x, y - p.y, z - p.z}; }
    SumPoint operator+(SumPoint const& p) const { return {x + p.x, y + p.y, z + p.z}; }
    bool operator==(SumPoint const& p) const = default;
    bool operator!=(SumPoint const& p) const = default;

    void SetPoint(float X, float Y, float Z) { x = X; y = Y; z = Z; }

    SumPoint& rotL90(unsigned char axis) {
        float f;
        switch (toupper(axis)) {
            case 'X': f = z; z = -y; y = f; break;
            case 'Y': f = z; z = -x; x = f; break;
            case 'Z': f = y; y = -x; x = f; break;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    float magnitude() const {
        using std::sqrt;
        using std::pow;
        return sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) + pow(z, 2));
    }

    void normalize() {
        float l = magnitude();
        x /= l; y /= l; z /= l;
    }

    float Distance(SumPoint const& p) const { return (p - *this).magnitude(); }

    glm::vec2 ToGlmVector() { return glm::vec2(x, y); }

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar& x& y& z; }
};


int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;

    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);

        std::vector<SumPoint> points{
            {1, 2, 3},
            {1, 2, 3, true},
            {-1, -2, -3, true},
        };
        oa << points;
    }

    std::cout << ss.str();

    {
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);

        std::vector<SumPoint> points;
        ia >> points;

        for (auto [x,y,z,smooth]: points) {
            std::cout << "\n -- SumPoint{" << x << "," << y << "," << z << (smooth ? ", smooth" : "") << "}";
        }
    }
}
```

Printing

```
22 serialization::archive 19 0 0 3 1 0 1 1.000000000e+00 2.000000000e+00 3.000000000e+00 1.000000000e+00 2.000000000e+00 3.000000000e+00 -1.000000000e+00 -2.000000000e+00 -3.000000000e+00

 -- SumPoint{1,2,3}
 -- SumPoint{1,2,3}
 -- SumPoint{-1,-2,-3}
```

Note that `isSmooth` is lost, because you didn't include it. Perhaps that's what you were adding the version for?

```
friend class boost::serialization::access;
template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned version) {
    ar& x& y& z;
    if (version > 1)
        ar& isSmooth;
}
```

Then with

```
BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(SumPoint, 2)
```

You get [Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1fea189776c413e):

```
22 serialization::archive 19 0 0 3 2 0 2 1.000000000e+00 2.000000000e+00 3.000000000e+00 0 1.000000000e+00 2.000000000e+00 3.000000000e+00 1 -1.000000000e+00 -2.000000000e+00 -3.000000000e+00 1

 -- SumPoint{1,2,3}
 -- SumPoint{1,2,3, smooth}
 -- SumPoint{-1,-2,-3, smooth}
```

Comment: @Thankyou very much , yes for isSmooth i was adding the new version number.